# suiteCRM API dates are incorrect

Tags: suitecrm

We recently did an upgrade on our CRM to version 7.12.5 (I'm not sure what version we upgraded from).  Previously, on the API, the dates I'd be looking at were always in +00:00 (GMT).  I.e., `01-01-2023T13:00:00Z-00:00`.  This is a correctly formated ISO8601 datetime representing Jan 1st 2023, 1PM, in GMT.

Now they are like `01-01-2023T13:00:00-05:00`.  Except that the `13:00:00` part is actually the GMT time stored in the MYSQL database.  So it's like a GMT time, with a -05:00 timezone slapped onto it.  This makes no sense to me.

An example- I create a record at 13:00:00 EST.  In MariaDB, it displays correctly as 18:00, but when I look at the record in an API call, it displays as `...T18:00:00-05:00`.

EDIT:  There's also situations where the `date_entered` and `date_modified` fields are in two different timezones(?!).  I.E.:

```
"attributes": {
    ...,
    "date_entered": "2018-09-17T13:38:00-04:00",
    "date_modified": "2020-02-27T16:12:00-05:00",
    ...
}
```

Previously, these were ALL in `-00:00`.

Any idea on why this could be?  I don't have full admin access on this server but I may be able to provide more information if needed.

Comment: The timezone somewhere has been set to EST, New York time. Check your settings somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the actual issue was, but the server admin restarted the server and it fixed itself.  If that doesn't work, try blowing on it.